# Steam login using openID in JAVA

Tags: java, authentication, openid, steam

I implemented Steam login in Java language.

However, if "is_valid:false" appears, I am worried that I cannot log in.

I'm worried because it's random to log in even if I deliver accurate information to the team.

my question is

I would definitely like to receive a response that it "is valid: true" if I deliver accurate information.

If that doesn't work, I'd like to know another way to log in

```
   @GetMapping("/login/check")
    public String startSession(
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.ns") String openidNs,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.mode") String openidMode,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.op_endpoint") String openidOpEndpoint,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.claimed_id") String openidClaimedId,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.identity") String openidIdentity,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.return_to") String openidReturnTo,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.response_nonce") String openidResponseNonce,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.assoc_handle") String openidAssocHandle,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.signed") String openidSigned,
        @RequestParam(value = "openid.sig") String openidSig,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException {


        log.info("openidResponseNonce = {} ", openidResponseNonce);

        ResponseEntity<String> block = WebClient.create("https://steamcommunity.com")
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/openid/login")
                .queryParam("openid.ns", openidNs)
                .queryParam("openid.mode", "check_authentication")
                .queryParam("openid.op_endpoint", openidOpEndpoint)
                .queryParam("openid.claimed_id", openidClaimedId)
                .queryParam("openid.identity", openidIdentity)
                .queryParam("openid.return_to", openidReturnTo)
                .queryParam("openid.response_nonce", openidResponseNonce)
                .queryParam("openid.assoc_handle", openidAssocHandle)
                .queryParam("openid.signed", openidSigned)
                .queryParam("openid.sig", openidSig)
                .build()
            )
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .block();

       
        boolean isTrue = Objects.requireNonNull(block).getBody().contains("true");

        log.info("isTrue = {} ", isTrue);
        if (!isTrue) {
            return "redirect:https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=" + baseUrl + "/login/check&openid.realm=" + baseUrl + "&openid.mode=checkid_setup";
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(openidIdentity);
        String steamId;

        if (matcher.find()) {
            steamId = matcher.group();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (!userService.findBySteamId(steamId).isPresent()) {
            userService.create(getUserInfo(steamId));
        }

        SecurityUser user = SecurityUser.builder()
            .id(userService.findBySteamId(steamId).get().getId())
            .username(userService.findBySteamId(steamId).get().getUsername())
            .steamId(steamId)
            .build();

        Authentication authentication = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(user, user.getAuthorities(), "steam");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        // 새로운 세션 생성
        session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        // 세션 ID를 쿠키에 설정
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.getId());
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return "redirect:/user/checkFirstVisit";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, I would recommend that you should have a look at [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html), rather then implementing security relevant things on your own. The library already deals with most of the topics, like handling tokens etc., if you configure it properly.